# Calling parent's method

Tags: c++, mosync

I'm kinda newbie to all this c++ stuff, so this probably is a beginner's problem:

ListScreen.h

```
#ifndef _LISTSCREEN_H_
#define _LISTSCREEN_H_

#include "MAUI/Screen.h"

namespace CoolPlaces {
    namespace Views {
        using namespace MAUI;

        class ListScreen : public Screen {
            public:
                ListScreen();
                ~ListScreen();

                void keyPressEvent(int keyCode, int nativeCode) {}
                void keyReleaseEvent(int keyCode, int nativeCode) {}
                void pointerPressEvent(MAPoint2d point) {}
                void pointerReleaseEvent(MAPoint2d point) {}
                void pointerMoveEvent(MAPoint2d point) {}
                void show();
        };
    }
}

#endif    //_LISTSCREEN_H_
```

ListScreen.cpp

```
  #include "MAUI/Screen.h"
#include "ListScreen.h"

using namespace MAUI;
using namespace CoolPlaces::Views;

void ListScreen::show() {
    Screen::show();
};
```

I'm getting this error: `D:\MosyncProjects\Views\ListScreen.cpp:22: Error: Unresolved symbol '__ZN4MAUI6Screen4showEv' line 22` in this `Screen::show();` call (for purpose of this topic I removed some code). So what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. That's a linker error, not a compiler error. You need to link the library which defines `Screen::show()`.

Comment: Damn... So what can I do? Restart my IDE, restart my computer? Format disks? :D

Comment: Apparently you didn't provide an implementation for `Screen::show()` or didn't link the object file/library where it resides.

Comment: _'Restart my IDE, restart my computer? Format disks?'_ Neither of these will correct your linker inputs ...

Comment: @Taylor I linked library with definition for show method (header file, right?), and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I did now - check the edited question.

Comment: Adding a header file to your project is not linking libraries.

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Did you write the source code for the Screen class.

Comment: @drescherjm actually I thought, that MoSync framework does that for me.

Comment: @drescherjm - no, MoSync developers did

Comment: I assume you are using mingw? What is the IDE that you use? I can't help much on mingw but others will be able..

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that MoSync IDE (which is built on top of Eclipse) doesn't use mingw. I don't know which compiler it uses.

Comment: Probably not related but not that `_LIST_SCREEN_` is a name reserved to the C++ implementation (i.e., the compiler and the standard library): any name starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved and shall not be touched in any way unless explicit permission is granted (like for `__FILE__` etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're including the header file, which tells that the function `Screen::show()` exists, but probably not linking the library, which has the implementation.

See this page: http://www.mosync.com/docs/sdk/cpp/guides/libs/working-with-mosync-libraries/index.html

Specifically:

> As well as referencing the header files in your application code, you also need to specify the actual libraries that you want to use in the project's Build Settings (Project > Properties > MoSync Project > Build Settings):

It looks like maui.lib should contain the screen code.